# How to retrieve the value from database to dynamic textbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

First of all, I have done add/remove input fields dynamically with jQuery. For example:

[image]

After, I'm using the `implode()` function of PHP I have stored dynamic textbox values into MySQL. For example

```php
$capture_field_vals = "";
if(isset($_POST["ItemCode"]) && is_array($_POST["ItemCode"])) {
    $capture_field_vals = implode(",", $_POST["ItemCode"]);     
}
```

From the above code, I can store Item Code As `[1000, 1001, 1004]` into the database. How can I retrieve the same values into a dynamic textbox again so user can edit or update it?

My PHPMyadmin :

[image]

PurchaserID is same as ItemCode. So, one lot can be contained one or more purchaser same as one purchaser can purchase one or more item.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: It totally depends on how you've stored in your database. Please share a screenshot of phpmyadmin.

Comment: Ok, Wait a minute.

Comment: @ObjectManipulator I done the edit.

Comment: use explode function.. then use array to store it in array...

Comment: @FullStack I have try it already. But I only able to store in first row's textbox. The dynamic second and third row won't come out.

Answer (score 0):

Select the PurchaseID as:

```
$query = Select purchaserID from table;

foreach($query as $data){
 $new_data = explode(',',$data);
 foreach($new_data as $row=>$val){
   $htmlRow .= <tr><td><input type="text" val=$val/></td></tr>; 
 }
}
```

now append $htmlRow to your table.

Comment: It gives me this error. Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()... And I dont understand how append $htmlRow to my table.

Comment: What is your $query output?

Comment: $query is not problem . It output the lot's purchaserID

Comment: Can you share the output , so that I can give you exact solution

Comment: Ohh.. Sorry, I think I make  you miss understanding dy. It only show . in the textbox. Second and third row doesn't come out also. I know $query is not problem because I echo the $query.

Comment: That's what I am saying to share the $query output so that I can look into it, not all just 2 or 3 rows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129330/discussion-between-rahul-and-eric).